# What can be an example of Vikalpa from our day-to-day life?

Tags: yoga, patanjali

Patanjali yoga sutras discuss five types of Chitta vrittis. One among them is vikalpa. The following is the sloka which defines vikalpa.

> शब्दज्ञानानुपाती वस्तुशून्यो विकल्पः Śabdajñānānupātī vastuśūnyo
> vikalpaḥ
>
> Vikalpa proceeds from a verbal cognition
> about something which is devoid of reality
>
> [[9, 1, Patanjali Yoga Sutras]](https://www.sanskrit-trikashaivism.com/en/patanjali-yoga-sutras/629)

I want to know a simple example that satisfies the above definition.

What can be an example for Vikalpa in our day-to-day life?

I am asking for an example from day-to-day life so that a sadhaka can be aware of vikalpa and then can handle it properly. So please refrain from giving examples that are very rare or from scientific experiments